struggling with farcaster frames
hi building my first farcaster frame (https://docs.farcaster.xyz/developers/frames/) using Next.js and Frog as the framework. I really struggling with deploying my frame onto Vercel and have been running in circles. My frame is simple with 3 CTA buttons, each linking to a different website. A simple image placeholder is a part of this idea. Can someone help me?
dont know where to start really because i have minimal cs background + no front end experience. chatgpt has not been helping, running around in circles editing my package.json, vercel.json, index.tsx, and tsconfig.json. i want to figure this outttttt

Can someone help me? is not a question about programming

what happens when you follow the tutorial?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
